# Page navigation - jQuery Mobile with knockout.js

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, navigation, viewmodel

I am working with a cross-platform mobile application using jQuery Mobile and knockout.js. I need to know the proper way to redirect to the next page. All of the examples I've seen illustrate a single HTML file with multiple pages. Is it possible to create individual HTML files for each page and maintain an individual JS file for each HTML page. Also, how do I link a view model with each individual page?

My questions are as follows...

1. How do I redirect from Index.html to Search.html and pass data between those pages?
2. How do I create individual HTML for each page and link with a view model?

***Working Code Example***

**Index.html**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="Index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>
                jQM</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-iscroll>
            This is jQM Testing
            <label for="arrCity">
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="autocomplete" data-bind="value:aCity" />
            <div data-bind="aCity">
            </div>
            <input id="btn" type="button" data-bind="click:showData" value="showData" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>
                jQM Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**search.html**

```
div id="second" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 data-bind="text: greeting">
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(ReqModel, document.getElementById('Index'));

});



var ReqModel = new ReqModel();
function ReqModel() {
    this.aCity = ko.observable('');
    this.showData = function () {
        alert(this.aCity());
        $.mobile.changePage("search.html");


    };
}
```

**search.js**

```
var ResviewModel = new ResviewModel(ReqModel);


function ResviewModel(data) {
    alert("this load");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var pre = document.getElementById('Index');
    ko.cleanNode(pre);
    ko.applyBindings(ResviewModel, document.getElementById('second'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your first question:

> How do I redirect from Index.html to Search.html and pass data between those pages?

I tackled the problem with [jQuery.navigate](https://github.com/michaelpapworth/jQuery.navigate), (also available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.navigate/)) I hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do this.
Instead of using input use anchor

```
<a href="search.html" id='btn' data-bind="click:showData">showData</a>
```

Make sure the function called return true or false

```
this.showData = function () {
    alert(this.aCity());
    return true
};
```

Return true will let you move to the next page.

For structural way you can see [this](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/knockoutjs-make-parent-and-child-structure-in-your-app/).